# Nodejs and Mongodb handle night shift

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I was trying to make an attendance application. I am using Mongodb and koajs for development. There is night shift option and I am unable to handle when the attendance date is changing. I need to move next dated first record to current dated record when the current dated shift is night. My current data set look like bellow.
[Mongodb Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P-KpgF8BL1O)

```
[
    {
        "date": "2023-04-01",
        "shift": {
            "_id": "6422d103994726677e9105c3",
            "date": "2023-04-01",
            "shiftType": {
                "_id": "6299fd7504978a2ba513e0a2",
                "name": "Next Day End",
                "isNight": true
            }
        },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6422d1b9994726677e9105c6",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-01T05:30:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-04-02",
        "shift": null, //Shift not yet set, treated as general shift.
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6422d1b9994726677e9105c7",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T00:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6423286e2746f65c2480a13e",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T04:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6423286e2746f65c2480a13f",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T12:40:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-04-03",
        "shiftType": {
                "_id": "6299fd7504978a2ba513e0a2",
                "name": "General",
                "isNight": false
            },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "642328a42746f65c2480a140",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-03T04:05:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "642328a42746f65c2480a141",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-03T13:45:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-04-04",
        "shift": {
            "_id": "6422d10a994726677e9105c5",
            "date": "2023-04-04",
            "shiftType": {
                "_id": "6299fd7504978a2ba513e0a2",
                "name": "Next Day End",
                "isNight": true
            }
        },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6423292f2746f65c2480a142",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-04T12:30:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-04-05",
        "shift": null,
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6423292f2746f65c2480a143",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-04T21:55:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

There are work shift and I have make lookup with attendance date and employee(I've not mentioned in the JSON). In my shift system have night duty provision as **shiftType** and here I am recording the night shift as `"isNight": true`.
So I need to marge the attendances with the next day attendance with where the isNight is true.
I need the output looks like Bellow.

```
[
    {
        "date": "2023-04-01",
        "shift": {
            "_id": "6422d103994726677e9105c3",
            "date": "2023-04-01",
            "shiftType": {
                "_id": "6299fd7504978a2ba513e0a2",
                "name": "Next Day End",
                "isNight": true
            }
        },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6422d1b9994726677e9105c6",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-01T05:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6422d1b9994726677e9105c7",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T00:30:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-04-02",
        "shift": null,
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6423286e2746f65c2480a13e",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T04:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6423286e2746f65c2480a13f",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T12:40:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-04-03",
        "shiftType": {
                "_id": "6299fd7504978a2ba513e0a2",
                "name": "General",
                "isNight": false
            },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "642328a42746f65c2480a140",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-03T04:05:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "642328a42746f65c2480a141",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-03T13:45:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-04-04",
        "shift": {
            "_id": "6422d10a994726677e9105c5",
            "date": "2023-04-04",
            "shiftType": {
                "_id": "6299fd7504978a2ba513e0a2",
                "name": "Next Day End",
                "isNight": true
            }
        },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6423292f2746f65c2480a142",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-04T12:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6423292f2746f65c2480a143",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-04T21:55:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.